# Difference between two zlib data ( same value )

Tags: python, python-3.x, zlib, deflate

I am working with zlib data from 3 days and I cannot get out of this problem:

The original zlib compressed data hex is as follows: `789c34c9410e82301005d0bbfc756b5a832ee62a94900146255620ed80314defae1b772f79050a5af6180df21feb06f2ce6002153c84930ec2dacf8b4a3a38821a7fbefcbed7c4a3805ab401775679f3c76e69b27bb6c259bd1d6cf3bc5d034c0978cd635a7300b993ab1dba5abf000000ffff`

And the hex that I generate using the zlib python library is the following: `789c35c9410e82301005d0bbfc756b5a832ee62a94900146255620ed80314defae1b772f79050a5af6180df21feb06f2ce6002153c84930ec2dacf8b4a3a38821a7fbefcbed7c4a3805ab401775679f3c76e69b27bb6c259bd1d6cf3bc5d034c0978cd635a7300b993ab1dba5abfb1bd28150000ffff`

Can anyone explain to me the difference between the two values?

```py
import zlib, json
ZLIB_SUFFIX = b'\x00\x00\xff\xff'
data = json.dumps({
        "t": None,
        "s": None,
        "op": 10,
        "d": {
            "heartbeat_interval": 41250,
            "_trace": [
                '["gateway-prd-us-east1-b-4kf6",{"micros":0.0}]'
            ]
        }
    }, separators=(',', ':')).encode('utf-8')
deflate = zlib.compressobj(6, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS)
result = deflate.compress(data) + deflate.flush() + ZLIB_SUFFIX
print(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

The original stream is not terminated, and hence invalid, and ends with an empty stored block. The one you generated *is* terminated and valid, but is followed by an extraneous `00 00 ff ff`. Both decompress to the same data, though the original is not validated with a check value. The one you generated is.

Your `ZLIB_SUFFIX` is not any such thing. What it *is* is a zero length and the complement of that length that would follow stored block header bits in a deflate stream. However it has no such meaning if it does *not* follow stored block header bits in a deflate stream, which is the case in the one you generated.